# Drawing a border between items, whether they fit side-by-side or wrap onto a new line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have two inline blocks, A and B, both of variable dimensions:

```html
<container style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap">
    <div>Arbitrary content A</div>
    <div>Arbitrary content B</div>
</container>
```

Depending on their content and the screen size, they might fit side-by-side, or B might need to go on a new line. This is readily achieved with flexbox, as demonstrated.

But whichever way it ends up being laid out, I would like to draw a line between the two blocks, like this:

```
AAA │ BBB
AAA │ BBB
```

```
AAA
AAA
───
BBB
BBB
```

Normally you’d solve this sort of layout thing with media queries, but because the layout is based on content, media queries won’t cut it.

With media queries ruled out, I can’t think of any good way of achieving this—anything like a `border` applies to a specified edge, and can’t be made to depend on the layout.

I don’t mind what layout technique is used, even if more DOM nodes need to be added to make it work, so long as JavaScript isn’t required. I’m pretty sure Grid can’t work, since that would require something like `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, auto)` which doesn’t work (`auto-fit` demands fixed dimensions).

I only care about the case of two items; three or more gets much messier and I’m fairly confident it’s not solvable with the tools to hand, whereas two feels like it might be solvable.

Anyone have any ideas on drawing this border?

Comment: even if you are self answering your question, we need to have a *question*. Actually I simply see a set of conditions/requirements without any attempt.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: your comment has some merit. Trouble is that I came up with the hacky solution I figured out well after I’d started writing the question, and then I edited the question poorly after that, essentially removing most of the evidence of attempts and leaving just the conditions I’d refined it to based on that. I’ve completely rewritten it now.

Part of the trouble is that this is a case where there’s nothing between a stub (which I initially omitted since it’s absolutely trivial, probably unwisely) and success.

Answer (score 2):

If transparency is not needed here is a solution that involve some background where you can easily control the size of your lines:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid;
  margin:10px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) center
    /
    calc(100% - 2*2px - 100px) /* length of horizontal line (we at least remove the thickness of the vertical line)*/
    calc(100% - 2*1px - 10px) /* length of vertical line (we at least remove the thickness of the horizontal line)*/
    no-repeat;
}
.container > * {
  padding:20px;
  background:#fff;
  flex-grow:1;
  margin:1px 2px; 
   /* 1px*2 = thickness of the horizontal line */ 
   /* 2px*2 = thickness of the vertical line */
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus vel venenatis sapien, </div>
  <div>Arbitrary content B</div>
</div>

<div class="container" >
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet </div>
  <div>Arbitrary content B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: An interesting solution! Another caveat here is that it must be acceptable to `flex-grow` the children; this means that if you want something like centre- or right-alignment inside that box, you’ll need to introduce another element; and if you don’t want the first child to consume spare space to left of the border when they’re laid side-by-side, use something like `flex-grow: 1` on the first child, and `flex-grow: 99999` on the last, so that it consumes roughly all the available space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution: give B one box-shadow one pixel above it and another one one pixel to the left of it, and then hide the unnecessary one with `overflow: hidden` on the container.

```css
container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 overflow: hidden;
 /* The next two are just to make the demo prettier. */
 border: 1px dashed #06f3;
 margin: 1em;
}

container > * {
 /* This is just to make the demo prettier. */
 padding: 1em;
}

container > :last-child {
 box-shadow: -1px 0 0 #fc0, 0 -1px 0 #fc0;
 /* This makes the line full-width if B wraps, rather than just B-width */
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<container>
 <a>a particularly long value to demonstrate just what happens when it wraps</a>
 <b>short value</b>
</container>

<container>
 <a>short value</a>
 <b>a particularly long value to demonstrate just what happens when it wraps</b>
</container>

<container>
 <a>a fairly long value to demonstrate things<br>subsequent<br>lines</a>
 <b>short value</b>
</container>

<container>
 <a>short value<br>subsequent<br>lines</a>
 <b>a fairly long value to demonstrate things</b>
</container>

<container>
 <a>a fairly long value to demonstrate things</a>
 <b>short value<br>subsequent<br>lines</b>
</container>

<container>
 <a>short value</a>
 <b>a fairly long value to demonstrate things<br>subsequent<br>lines</b>
</container>
```

Needing to use `overflow: hidden` is not ideal, but will often be acceptable.

The use of box-shadows incidentally allows a few interesting things:

- You can adjust the length and position of the drawn line by using a negative spread-radius, e.g. `box-shadow: calc(-1em - 1px) 0 0 -1em #fc0, 0 calc(-1em - 1px) 0 -1em #fc0`.
- You can draw a different style of border depending on whether the line is horizontal or vertical, by tweaking the two box-shadows.